# Class Design with Generic Class and Interface in C#

Tags: c#, generics, class-design, generic-interface

I am working on an old piece of code and trying to implement it afresh with the new advancements in .NET. However I can't wrap my head around the design for the same. Previously there were no template classes/interfaces and now I need to make use of the same. I will try to give an example of the design and where I am getting stuck. The design is something like this :

```
interface Service<T>
{
    T Value;
    Task AsyncWork();
}

class Input<T> : Service<T>, Input
{
    Worker w1;
    Task AsyncWork()
    {
        w1.WorkOnInput(this); //error
        ... //will return a Task eventually
    }

}

class Input
{
    //common members and methods for child classes
    int priority;
    string Name;
    FormatInput()
    {
        //some common implementation
    }

}

class StringInput:Input<string>
{
    //Implementation specific to string input
}

class IntInput:Input<int>
{
    //Implementation specific to int input
}

class Worker
{
    WorkOnInput(Input)
    {
        ...
    }
}

Main()
{
    Worker w = new Worker();
    Input input1 = new StringInput();
    Input input2 = new IntInput();
    input1.FormatInput();
    input2.FormatInput();
    List<Input> inputList = new List<Input>();
    inputList.Add(input1);
    inputList.Add(input2);
    AnotherMethod(inputList); //another method which expects a list of Inputs
    w.WorkOnInput(input1);
    w.WorkOnInput(input2);
}
```

I cannot change the interface implementation as I am not the owner of the same. But as the comment shows I would have an error at `w1.WorkOnInput(this)`, since this here expects `Input` type and not `Input<T>`.

However if I change the `WorkOnInput` to accept an argument of type `Input<T>` then I would have to make it a generic method as `WorkOnInput<T>` and if I would need to call it I would explicitly have to provide the type of the input which is also not desirable.

Also I have a list of inputs which is needed to be passed to `AnotherMethod()` and a `List<Input<T>>` is not possible.

I think I am getting a bit too confused with the scenario and am going round and round without any concrete solution.

Can someone please point me into the right direction?

Comment: Shouldn't `class Input<T> : Service<T>, Input`  be `class Input<T> : Input, Service<T>` ?   ... and if you can, you should rename `Service<T>` as `IService<T>`

Comment: Have you tried `w1.WorkOnInput((Input)this);` ?

Comment: So make a `public class TList<T> : List<Input<T>> {}`

Comment: @CharlesBretana, this is not really the actual code, I was just trying to explain the problem. That is why I didn't really think about coding conventions. I highlighted the List<Input> part since I do infact need a list of the base class type.

Comment: @tomab it doesn't work because Input is the base class of Input<T>, so a cast shouldn't at all be needed infact, however since it is generic class, the case is now different and it cannot implicitly of explicitly (with the help of a cast) convert Input<T> to Input.

Comment: First, read again the first part of @CharlesBretana comment.  It's not just about coding conventions. If you don't specify the base class before the interface, the code above does not compile at all. Second, generic or not, Input<T> is implicitly castable to Input, so the code above should work. You'd better show what `Worker` class looks like and what exact compiler error you are getting.

Comment: your `Worker.WorkOnInput` method is **private**, how do you expect to be called?

Comment: Huge mistake on my part, I apologize to @CharlesBretana, I missed out the first and more important part of your comment. Could you please add this as an answer so that I can mark it as an answer.@Ivan Stoev Thank you for the eye opener.

Comment: @Ricky... Sign of a mature, reasonable person, is graceful acknowledgement when you make a mistake.  no worries, been there done that, have the T-Shirt !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't `class Input<T> : Service<T>, Input` be `class Input<T> : Input, Service<T>` ?

... and if you can, you should rename `Service<T>` as `IService<T>` - It is an interface not a class. By following best practice naming conventions, it would make writing

```
class Input<T> : IService<T>, Input
```

clearly and obviously wrong, cause the interface dependency is listed before the one and only allowed base class.